# Angular - save data from register form

Tags: angular

I have a register form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
```

I would like add input text as a new object in my component. 
I programming in angular 5.
What is the simplest way?

Comment: Please refer this link [https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Comment: can I please for example?

Comment: Can I add `FormGroup` when I have `<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">` ?

Comment: Yes, You can add `form-group` class. Sorry, I am not sure about the question you are trying to ask.

Comment: I have a : `email: string` in my component; i would like to bind text input to my email pole.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this would be through two-way data binding. The first thing that you need to do is add FormsModule to the NgModule list of imports as follows.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // MAKE SURE THIS IS IMPORTED

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule // MAKE SURE THIS IS ADDED
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then you'd need to update your component .html file to use two-way data binding. This binds the specified element to a property that you have on your component's .ts file.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

Then finally, ensure that you have _fname and _lname properties in the form's .ts file.

```
export class SomeComponent {
    email = "";

    // Implement a function like this when submitting the form
    save() { 
        console.log(this.email);
        // Do whatever you'd like with this.email
    }
}
```